# Why a directive doesn't watch the value change?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a directive looking like this:

```
directive('parcelsCarousel',function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        replace:true,
        transclude:true,
        templateUrl:'/partials/parcels-carousel.html',
        link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('favoriteParcelsList', function (favoriteParcelsList) {
                if (scope.favoriteParcelsList != undefined)
                    console.log(scope.favoriteParcelsList.length)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I push an item to `favoriteParcelsList` from the controller, but the $watch doesn't run.
What can I do the wrong way? I am sure I am missing something small thing because I have a couple of other directives having similar structure and they work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing more code (ideally live, in a plunker) would be ideal to say for sure but I suspect that you want to add elements to the `favoriteParcelsList` and have AngularJS picking up those changes. If so it needs to be noted that by default `$watch` tracks identity of objects. If you want to track content of more complex objects you need to use deep-watch.

You can instruct AngularJS to deep-watch for changes by supplying third, boolean parameter to the `$watch` method (notice **true** at the end):

```
        scope.$watch('favoriteParcelsList', function (favoriteParcelsList) {
            if (scope.favoriteParcelsList != undefined)
                console.log(scope.favoriteParcelsList.length)
        }, true);
```

Comment: But why does one need a full comparison of the object if one just wants to detect the length? I asking because I could imagine that it slows things down but I maybe got something wrong. :)

Comment: Deep watch will slow things down, you are right. If you just want to detect length changes watch the length property: `scope.$watch('favoriteParcelsList.length', ...`